# why typing *import this* in python jupyter produces some string text which looks like a poetry?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

so I am still a newbie in the python world and started learning it yesterday, I am using **Jupyter** text editor with **anaconda 3**.

so I was exploring a website online on [Opening a Jupyter Notebook](https://problemsolvingwithpython.com/02-Jupyter-Notebooks/02.04-Opening-a-Jupyter-Notebook/#:%7E:text=Open%20a%20Jupyter%20Notebook%20with%20Anaconda%20Navigator,-One%20additional%20way&text=Open%20Anaconda%20Navigator%20using%20the,%2D%2D%3E%20%5BAnaconda%20Navigator%5D.&text=A%20Jupyter%20file%20browser%20will%20open%20in%20a%20web%20browser%20tab.&text=%3E%20%5BPython%203%5D-,A%20new%20notebook%20will%20open%20as,tab%20in%20your%20web%20browser.) and I came to a line where the website said :

> Try typing the code below in the first cell in the notebook to the
> right of the In [ ]: prompt:
>
> ```
> import this
> ```
>
> Then click the run button in the middle of the menu at the top of the
> notebook.

they didn't explain what is this line and didn't even mention its output.

so I wrote this line in **Jupyter** :

```
import this
```

and when I run this command only, I got this strange output that looks like a poem to me:

```
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
Complex is better than complicated.
Flat is better than nested.
Sparse is better than dense.
Readability counts.
Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
Although practicality beats purity.
Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced.
In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
Now is better than never.
Although never is often better than *right* now.
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!
```

I guess that the `import` keyword means to *import a package*, but what does the sentence `import this` even mean and where does this strange output which looks like a poem comes from?